# At what point in recovery mode should ADB be available?

Tags: adb, recovery-mode

I am using stock Android on a Nexus 5X, and I have a phone that is generally in a bootloader loop (unless the phone is frozen cold — weirdest bug I've ever seen).  I can now consistently get into recovery mode, and am hoping to pull some data off of it with ADB.

The catch is, I can't seem to get my computer to recognize the phone through ADB so that I can issue an `adb pull` command.  It's not a question of bad drivers, etc.  If I choose "Apply update from ADB", the device lists under `adb devices`, but I cannot issue any command except `sideload` which is not what I want.  (this question is different from the many "similar questions" that SE recommends as they deal with a driver issue, etc, where ADB never shows up.

I have a Nexus 5 that functions fully and likewise on it, I can't seem to figure out when I should be able to issue ADB commands other than `sideload`.

Is this is a question of using stock recovery?  Or is there another way to kickstart ADB that allows commands other than `sideload`.

Comment: Stock recovery - only when using sideload. Custom recovery - all the time. Conclusion: flash a custom recovery if possible.

Comment: @AndyYan Ugh, why would stock make that limitation?  I don't think I can flash a custom recovery because the bootloader is locked (I thought I had unlocked it but apparently not).  Well, guess I need to just hope I can fully complete the boot sequence the next time I pull it out of the freezer.  Feel free to add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: You might be able to `fastboot boot` a custom recovery without flashing.

Comment: @MatthewRead I tried that, but (at least with TWRP) it bails with `FAILED (remote: not supported in locked device)`.

Comment: ADB in stock recovery means anyone can tamper with and transfer your data even when you have a locked bootloader - definitely not the security level you want.

Comment: @AndyYan I think most people would be okay with that — just say "Hey, flashing this could allow access to your data.  Just to make sure you're really you and not an evil nefarious person, please input the primary user's screen unlock code / password.  You have 5 tries before user data is wiped," and then maybe users very concerned about their data could block that style recovery.